# Query regarding tsv file parsing in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-maps-api-3

I have written a python function which is going to calculate the distance between two points, using google api. The function is as shown below:

import urllib
import json as simplejson

```
def calculateDistance(sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude):
        sourceCoordinates = sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude
        destinationCoordinates = destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude

        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(sourceCoordinates),str(destinationCoordinates))
        result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
        resulting_distance = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
        print "The distance is: " + resulting_distance

#calculateDistance(5.341612, -3.913602,5.342044, -4.143452)
#calculateDistance(5.342044, -4.143452,5.341612, -3.913602)
```

I have a tsv file which looks like this:

```
-4.143452    5.342044
-3.913602    5.341612
-3.967045    5.263331
     ....
     ....
```

The first column represents the longitude and the second column the latitude.

Now, i want to pass every combination of these values to my function to get the distance between the points. Could anybody let me know an efficient way to do this? The tsv file is pretty huge.

Answer (score 0):

```
Points=[]
with open('file.tsv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
            Points.append(line.strip().split('\t'))
for combo in itertools.combinations(Points, 2):
    calculateDistance(combo[0][0], combo[0][1], combo[1][0], combo[1][1])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Could you please let me know how i could pass every combination of the values present in the list to the function?

Comment: Do you want to pass each line one by one to the function or all in one shot ?

Comment: i want to pass each line one by one and try out all possible combination.